# Most memory-efficient map in java

Tags: java, memory-management, dictionary

I am implementing a tree-like structure using the `Map` interface like the following declaration:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<Integer, Double>>>
```

Currently I am using the `HashMap` implementation.
After loading a huge amount of data, I am seeing the program consume 4GB of RAM.
On persisting the whole entity using the `Serializable` interface, the resulting file's size is just 1GB.

What is the most memory-efficient `Map` implementation that I could use here?

Comment: Is using maps the right solution? Shouldn't you use a `List<FirstLevelNode>`, with `FirstLevelNode` holding a `List<SecondLevelNode>`, and `SecondLevelNode` holding a `List<ThirdLevelNode>`?

Comment: Wont using list affect the performance of retrieval. I am fine with larger load time but retrieval time is what i am trying to save here.

Comment: Maybe. We don't know what you're doing with your tree.

Comment: It is strange to call this structure a tree. It is indeed tree-shaped, assuming that none of the values in the map are coupled with more than key. Otherwise, you'd have a graph. In order to give you the best answer, you need to describe the access pattern for this structure. Do you usually have two strings and an integer in hand for which you want to find the corresponding double value? Or do you need to grab subtrees (say, given just the first string) and pass those around as well? Restated: Is this really a mapping from a composite key (a tuple of two strings and an integer) to a double?

Comment: All i want is to map a (String,String,Integer) -> Float . As there is a large volume of such data , its very important to achieve the most efficient method here.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to map a (String,String,Integer) to a Float, then the best thing to do is to use a `Map<MyKey, Float>`, where `MyKey` would be defined like this:

```
public final class MyKey {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;
    private final Integer c;

    public MyKey(String a, String b, Integer c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    // getters, if needed

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(a, b, c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof MyKey)) {
            return false;
        }
        MyKey other = (MyKey) o;
        return Objects.equal(a, o.a)
               && Objects.equal(b, o.b)
               && Objects.equal(c, o.c);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a *correct* way to do it, but it does not address the OP's question as to which way is *most efficient* in terms of memory consumed by the structure. Here we add the overhead of a four object headers per key. There's another design that would use just two headers per key: a dummy type wrapped around a byte array.

Comment: +1 for this solution over @seh's.  The real issue is avoiding the overhead incurred by the three nested maps; fancier approaches require significantly more work for minimal benefit.

Comment: Agreed. But it would already be a lot more efficient than maps of maps of maps. I would go with a clear and simple solution first, and see if it needs additional optimization only after.

Comment: Well, sure, but the OP didn't ask *whether* he should care about such things. He said that he does, and I take him at his word that he'd like to learn more about storage overhead through our answers (and, in this case, our probing questions too).

Comment: @seh - I cant see how this is a solution. Here you are mapping  (String,String,Integer)  to a unique hashcode of integer type. This might not be possilbe in my case as there is a huge volume of such data and 2^32 integers wont be able to represent them all. My volume of data would be much higher than that.

Comment: I didn't suggest such a direct mapping. Rather, you can concatenate the two strings and the integer into a byte array, and rely on `Arrays#hashCode(byte[])` to compute the hash code for the concatenated key. Any collisions get resolved as normal via `Arrays#equals(byte[], byte[])`. You can't use byte arrays directly here, for lack of proper `hashCode()` and `equals()` semantics; hence my mention of a "dummy type" wrapping the byte array. As for the concatenation encoding, SQLite has a nice design I've used elsewhere: http://www.sqlite.org/src4/doc/trunk/www/key_encoding.wiki

Answer (score 3):

You have two kinds of maps here. One which has String keys and Map values. For that I'd probably use [Google Guava's ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) if immutability is ok for you. It will probably not save you a lot of memory, but it might save you some, and perform a bit better than a normal HashMap.

For the other Map with Integer keys and Double values, you should use a specialized Map implementation which stores primitives instead of objects. Take for instance a look at [Trove4j's TIntDoubleHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/index.html?gnu/trove/TLongIntHashMap.html). This will save you a lot of memory, as the primitives are stored as primitives instead of Objects.